# Do you have to actively direct a Mage's Sword?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I was looking at [Mage's Sword](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/mageSSword.html) and noticed that in the spell description it states if you are not directing it the sword returns to you.  The spell description also states that the sword continues attacking its target if you do not use a standard action to direct it to a new target.  Below are the relevant sections of the spell description.

> If the sword goes beyond the spell range from you, goes out of your sight, or you are not directing it, it returns to you and hovers.

and

> Each round after the first, you can use a standard action to switch the sword to a new target. If you do not, the sword continues to attack the previous round's target.

Is there some unspecified action that needs to be taken to keep the sword attacking the target and not return to you?

Does this mean if you cast the spell twice, only the most recently directed sword attacks, with the other returning to you since you aren't directing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the language is a little awkward, I believe the description is trying to say that the sword will attack whatever target is designated when cast, requiring no action to continue attacking that target each round. Designating a new target requires a standard action. The only time the 'return to caster' clause should trigger would be when the designated target is no longer available (dead, out of range or sight), and the caster has not designated a new target during his turn (either due to not having any valid targets, or not wanting to designate a new target, or not having any standard actions available).

Answer (score 1):

### No, you dont. Unless you want to switch targets

That sentence about returning the sword has caused confusion before, but keep in mind that Mage's Sword works similarly to [Spiritual Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/spiritualWeapon.html#spiritual-weapon) in a lot of ways, including on how it returns to you. You are *directing* the sword when you decide that it should attack an enemy, as described by this line:

> The sword strikes at any opponent within its range, **as you desire**, starting in the round that you cast the spell. The sword attacks its designated target once each round on your turn.

While [Spiritual Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/spiritualWeapon.html#spiritual-weapon) used a different word there:

> A weapon made of force appears and attacks foes at a distance, **as you direct it** (...) Each round after the first, you can use a move action to **redirect** the weapon to a new target. (...) If the weapon goes beyond the spell range, if it goes out of your sight, or **if you are not directing it**, the weapon returns to you and hovers.

By using a different word there (desire instead of direction), the author of the spell caused this confusion.

The sword is being directed when you direct it to attack a creature, and will not become *"undirected"* unless that creature dies, when it flies back to you and hovers.

> If the sword goes beyond the spell range from you, goes out of your sight, or you are not directing it, it returns to you and hovers.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the intention was to make the sword attack as long as the wizard decides to continue attacking (that's not explicitely stated but it makes sense for that to be a free action). So if the wizard can't make this decision (like if he is stunned, petrified, dead...) the sword would come back to him and hover.

The only way to be really sure about this would be to Word of God, but as far as I know there is none about this spell.